# How to get the name of a method's class in Python?

Tags: python, function, class, methods, module

I need a function that gets the name of a method's module, ie:

```
import torch
t = torch.Tensor(...)# arguments don't matter
foo(t)
>>>torch
```

I know `__name__` exists, but it doesn't do what I need

Answer (score 0):

To get the name of the module which supports a particular class or function, you need to use the `__class__.__module__` properties:

```
import numpy as np

t = np.matrix([])
print(t.__class__.__module__)
```

Answer (score 0):

The class name:

```
>>> import torch
>>> t = torch.Tensor()
>>> type(t).__name__
'Tensor'
```

The module name:

```
>>> t.__module__
'torch'
```

Comment: `__qualname__` is also useful if you want both as a single string

Comment: @kindall Not quite, the `torch.Tensor.__qualname__` would still be just "Tensor" here, since that's the top-level name. The qualname is for identifying [nested scopes](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-qualified-name).

Comment: _`__qualname__` doesn’t include the module name_ - ref https://peps.python.org/pep-3155/#excluding-the-module-name